# Cannot iterate over a bit representation of an int

Tags: c#

I need to loop through a bit representation of an integer then I need to calculate the number of zeroes in it. I tired the below code but unfortunately it did not work :

```
public int calculate(int i)
{
            string a = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
            int[] array = new int[a.Length];
            int number = 0;

            for (int n = 0; n < s.Length; n++)
            {
                iarray[n] = s[n]; // build an array of intigers representing the bits valies such as 0011100
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < array.Length; n++)
            {
                if (array[n] == 0) {
                   number = number + 1;
            }

            return number
}
```

Can anyone advice why it is not working as intended ?

Comment: Why not just iterate over the string? And if you only want to count the zeroes, why are you converting it to a string at all rather than using bit operations?

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Where's the variable s coming from? shouldn't that be a

Comment: @Rawling i tired to create an array of Byte[] but it did not work

Comment: Should it return 1 when the input is 0?

Comment: It's an **`integer`** - not an `intiger`

Answer (score 5):

The reason it didn't work is that you are comparing characters (`'0'`, value 48 != `0`)

Just use bit operators, using *unsigned* math to avoid complications from right-shifting negative numbers:

To count all zeros:

```
var u = (uint)i;
int count = 0;
for(int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++)
{
    if((u & 1)==0) count++;
    u  = u >> 1;
}
```

To count just the zeros up to the most significant set bit:

```
var u = (uint)i;
int count = 0;
while(u != 0)
{
    if((u & 1)==0) count++;
    u  = u >> 1;
}
```

There are more exotic ways of doing this if you need to optimize.

Comment: Won't this count _all_ the zeroes? (I'd use `while u > 0` myself.)

Comment: @Rawling that *seems* to be the intent, no? But if not, the OP can adjust to suit (or clarify the question). The main point: don't use strings to perform bitops. If he only wants the zeros after the most significant 1, that can be done too.

Comment: Using the string conversion gets rid of the leading zeroes. (I _did_ see the original question so have a bit more context.)

Comment: @MarcGravell I like the elegant solution of how you end the loop, when the leading zeroes are not required. Very nice, and doesn't require any computational power (I computed log2 of i to get this, which is sloooow...)

Comment: I think I like this one better than my own answer.

Comment: @MarcGravell Now I really hate you - in a good way, if you know what I mean. Accept my congratulations, this is the summit of this problem...

Answer (score 2):

You only need it.

```
int a = 258;
string str = Convert.ToString(a, 2);
var count = str.Where(c => c == '0').Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int SignificantZeroCount(int x)
{
    int mask = x | (x >> 16);
    mask |= mask >> 8;
    mask |= mask >> 4;
    mask |= mask >> 2;
    mask |= mask >> 1;

    int y = mask ^ x;
    int c = 0;
    while (y != 0)
    {
        c++;
        y &= y - 1;
    }
    return c;
}
```

First a `mask` is calculated that has all bits at and to the right of the leftmost 1-bit in `x` set. Xorring that with `x` puts the significant zeroes of `x` in `y` (as ones), but not the leading zeroes. Then the ones in `y` are counted, which is the same as counting the significant zeroes in `x`.

Comment: This works. I would have to sit down very carefully with a pen and paper to figure out *how* it works, but it definitely works!

Comment: @MarcGravell I still likes yours better, mainly because the calculation of that mask doesn't really make me happy.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the ASCII value in array[]. Use a conversion like this to get what you want:

```
    public static int calculate(int i)
        {
            string a = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
            int[] array = new int[a.Length];
            int number = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < a.Length; n++)
            {
                array[n] = Convert.ToInt32(a[n].ToString()); // build an array of intigers representing the bits valies such as 0011100
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < array.Length; n++)
            {
                if (array[n] == 0)
                {
                    number = number + 1;
                }
            }
            return number;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public int calculate(int i)
            {
        string a = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
        int number = 0

        for (int i=0;i<a.Lenght;i++){
              if (a.Substring(i,1).Equals("0"))
                   number++;
        }

        return number;


    }
```

Comment: You really should use `if (array[n] == '0')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetBits(int n)
{
    int m = 1;
    while(m <= n)
    {
        if((n & m) == m)
            yield return 1;
        else
            yield return 0;
        m <<= 1;
    }
}

var numberOfZeros = GetBits(42).Count(x => x == 0);
```

Note that this will only return the *significant* zeros, i.e. 3 for the number 42.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your approach would be like this:

```
public int calculate(int i) {
    string a = Convert.ToString(i, 2);


    int[] array = new int[a.Length];
    int number = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < a.Length; n++) {
        iarray[n] = int.parse(a[n]);              
    }               
    for (int n = 0; n < array.Length; n++) {
        if (array[n] == 0) {
             number = number + 1;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

But this is a bad approach... Why would you want to convert an integer to a String, when you can do without that? Of course it's a bit trickier...

I'd do it like this:

```
public int calculate(int i) {
    int bits = 1+Math.log(i) / Math.log(2)
    int zerocount = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<bits;j++) {
        if(i%2==0) {
            zeroCount++;
        }
        i==i>>1;
    }
    return zeroCount;
}
```

**EDIT** Which is not the best solution either, because `Math.log` is not too quick. Use Marc's solution to get a much quicker, much more elegant result!

Comment: `Math.Log` is a relatively expensive operation... that might be an unoptimization

Comment: @MarcGravell: as I wrote in my comment, I like your approach a lot better, somehow it didn't occur to me that it is so easy to determine when to stop... Well, if the `ToString()` uses your approach (and why wouldn't it), then I unintendedly did really present a much worse solution...

Comment: The world would be a better place if there were `Math.BitScanForward` and `Math.BitScanReverse`